# Python some special products of a given list

Tags: python

I would like to find a way for the possible products of the given list. Below, I have an example

So far, I tried this :

```
for p in itertools.product(the_list, repeat=2):
        print p
```

But, this returns all the possibilities that can be generated from the given list. Can you please help me to generate the following example ?

An example:

```
the_list=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']
The results should be: 
['A1A2','A1B2','A1C2','A1D2','A2A3','A2B3','A2C3','A2D3','A3A1','A3B1','A3C1','A3D1'
 'B1A2,'B2A3'...
 'C1A2'...']
```

Basically, the Capital letters refer the state and the numbers refer the sequence. So, if it starts with A1, it can only continue with a state with the number 2, for example first A1, then A2 or B2 or C2 or D2. It is also circular which means A3 is followed either by A1,B1,C1 or D1.

Comment: This is something you're probably going to have to write manually, with a loop. Break it down in English (like you have started to), and go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I'm getting confused... you say it can't start with `'B2'` but `'B2A3'` is valid...

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I misunderstood your first question. it can start both B1 and B2.

Comment: By "A3 follows either A1,B1,C1 or D1", do you actually mean the exact opposite, i.e. "A3 is *followed by* A1, B1, C1, or D1"?

Comment: I meant like that 'A3A1', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 'A3D1'...

Comment: But in "A3A1", "A3" *is followed by* "A1".  "A3 follows A1" would be "A1A3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']
result = [i + j for i in l for j in l if int(j[1]) == int(i[1]) + 1 or (j[1] == '1' and i[1] == '3')]
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
['A1A2', 'A1B2', 'A1C2', 'A1D2', 'A2A3', 'A2B3', 'A2C3', 'A2D3', 'A3A1', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 'A3D1', 'B1A2', 'B1B2', 'B1C2', 'B1D2', 'B2A3', 'B2B3', 'B2C3', 'B2D3', 'B3A1', 'B3B1', 'B3C1', 'B3D1', 'C1A2', 'C1B2', 'C1C2', 'C1D2', 'C2A3', 'C2B3', 'C2C3', 'C2D3', 'C3A1', 'C3B1', 'C3C1', 'C3D1', 'D1A2', 'D1B2', 'D1C2', 'D1D2', 'D2A3', 'D2B3', 'D2C3', 'D2D3', 'D3A1', 'D3B1', 'D3C1', 'D3D1']
```

If you prefer readability over compactness, then break up the one-liner

```
l=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']
result = []
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        if int(j[1]) == int(i[1]) + 1 or (j[1] == '1' and i[1] == '3'):
            result.append(i+j)
print(result)
```

It outputs the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current list there aren't too many values to eliminate if you want to just get all the permutations and filter the undesirables after the fact. Do this lazily and the ones you filter will be far less common than the ones you keep. (I'll use a list comprehension for transparency – turn it into a generator expression in your actual code.)

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> [''.join(x) for x in permutations(l, 2) if int(x[0][1]) % 3 == int(x[1][1]) - 1]
['A1A2', 'A1B2', 'A1C2', 'A1D2', 'A2A3', 'A2B3', 'A2C3', 'A2D3', 'A3A1', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 'A3D1', 'B1A2', 'B1B2', 'B1C2', 'B1D2', 'B2A3', 'B2B3', 'B2C3', 'B2D3', 'B3A1', 'B3B1', 'B3C1', 'B3D1', 'C1A2', 'C1B2', 'C1C2', 'C1D2', 'C2A3', 'C2B3', 'C2C3', 'C2D3', 'C3A1', 'C3B1', 'C3C1', 'C3D1', 'D1A2', 'D1B2', 'D1C2', 'D1D2', 'D2A3', 'D2B3', 'D2C3', 'D2D3', 'D3A1', 'D3B1', 'D3C1', 'D3D1']
```

**Update** to answer John's comment:
Assuming each state has the same sequence size:

```
>>> seq_size = len([x for x in l if x[0] == 'A']) # Get the length of the sequence of A
>>> [''.join(x) for x in permutations(l, 2) if int(x[0][1:]) % seq_size == int(x[1][1:]) - 1]
```

**Update** to generalize for John's next series of comments:

```
#!env python

'''Get all the permutations of pieces up to a certain size
    where the sequence numbers of each piece occur in order, cyclically.
    So for a permutation_size of 5, 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->1.'''

from string import uppercase
from itertools import permutations

num_states = 5
seq_size = 13
group_size = 3

the_list = [char + str(1 + num) for char in uppercase[:num_states] for num in xrange(seq_size)]

def groupFilter(pieces):
    '''True for a list whose sequence is in order. False otherwise.'''
    ints = [int(piece.lstrip(uppercase)) for piece in pieces]
    offset = ints[0] % seq_size
    for i, piece in enumerate(ints):
        if offset + i != piece % seq_size:
            return False
    return True

[''.join(group) for group in permutations(the_list, group_size) if groupFilter(group)]
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP is after: all of the examples have numbers which are (cyclically) consecutive.

Comment: ^ and you need to consider A3A1 for example.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand the requirements. Updated – is that better?

Comment: No problem, it is better. How about the indices are two lines, for example A15, how are you going to update your code ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Your description of the problem does not account for A3A0. A3A0 could only happen if `initial_list = ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B0', 'B1', …]`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to say A3A1. If I want to run this for larger list, and with the larger index numbers like [A1-A9, B1-B9 C1-C9,...,Z1-Z9]. Can you update your code to do that ?

Comment: @JohnSmith But your specification isn't clear. Your original spec *implies* that A3A1 is only valid if there are three values per state. If there are four, 'A3A1' should be invalid, but 'A4A1' would be valid. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, so basically the index can be followed by a number that is next to that number such as A3A4,A3Z4... or circular number A9D0, D9Z0... Circular depends on the max index in the latter case is 9.

Comment: @JohnSmith OK, so A3A1 would be invalid for A1-A9. So my solution is correct.

Comment: One more thing, it should be expendable to large scale, for example so far we considered 2 sequence A1A2. Can we do it 3 scale or more something like A1A2A3, for 4 scale A1A2A3A4.

Comment: @JohnSmith OK. Updated again. This is really not how StackOverflow's supposed to work, and if your values really are sequences of letters and numbers you could probably *generate* the correct final result much more simply if you just state how many states and sequence size from the beginning. But anyway, I've updated my answer under the assumption that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it up by the sequence, by having

```
first = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']
second = ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2']
...
```

Then, taking the product of two consecutive lists should give you what you want (if I understand your question correctly...).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wanted something that may work with `itertools.product`, you could try this (happy to tweak if it doesn't match your 'real' input - it's an interesting problem :) ). This could be wrapped up into fewer lines, but it loses a lot of readability, so hopefully this will be somewhat useful:

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter


the_list = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']

# In order to work properly with groupby, we sort the list by the
# number at the end of the string
s = sorted(the_list, key=itemgetter(-1))

# Now we create a list of lists, each sub-list containing values
# with the same ending number (i.e. ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'])
j = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(s, key=itemgetter(-1))]

# Now we create our final list
results = []

# Here we iterate through our grouped lists, using product
# similar to how you did before to create the combined strings
for index, r in enumerate(j):

    # This is the piece that lets us 'loop' the list -
    # on the first iteration, the value is -(3)+1+0 = -2,
    # which we use as our list index. This will return the item
    # 'ahead' of the current one in our main list, and when it
    # reaches the last (index=2) item, the value is -(3)+1+2 = 0 (beginning)
    inc = -len(j) + 1 + index

    # Now we just iterate through the items in our sub-list, pairing with
    # the items in the 'next' sub-list
    for val in r:
        results += [k+v for k, v in product([val], j[inc])]

print results
```

Output:

```
['A1A2', 'A1B2', 'A1C2', 'A1D2', 
 'B1A2', 'B1B2', 'B1C2', 'B1D2', 
 'C1A2', 'C1B2', 'C1C2', 'C1D2', 
 'D1A2', 'D1B2', 'D1C2', 'D1D2', '
  A2A3', 'A2B3', 'A2C3', 'A2D3', 
 'B2A3', 'B2B3', 'B2C3', 'B2D3', 
 'C2A3', 'C2B3', 'C2C3', 'C2D3', 
 'D2A3', 'D2B3', 'D2C3', 'D2D3', 
 'A3A1', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 'A3D1', 
 'B3A1', 'B3B1', 'B3C1', 'B3D1', 
 'C3A1', 'C3B1', 'C3C1', 'C3D1', 
 'D3A1', 'D3B1', 'D3C1', 'D3D1']
```